# How to add xml file to layout view android

Tags: android, json, xml

i have file xml android ui  on my device i want read this file on app

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_primry2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home_splash">

</RelativeLayout>
```

like this

```
File file = "Element/0/....../RelativeLayout .xml"
View view = file ;
setcontentview(view);
```

Important note, this is not a real code, but this is a code that explains what I want

Comment: You should add it to the /layout folder in your project

Comment: Is there another way to meet that?

Comment: @kerolsnaguib Do you want to load xml file outside the project directory?

Comment: @Thân LƯƠNG yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XmlPullParser` to create an `AttributeSet` and pass it when you create your `View`. Use an `InputStream` such as `FileInputStream`.

Example (change what you need to adapt it to your app):

```
    File path = getFilesDir(); // Or the place where you want to save your files
    String fileName = "my_xml_file.xml";
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    FileInputStream fis;
    XmlPullParserFactory xppFactory;
    XmlPullParser xpp;
    AttributeSet attrs;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        xppFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xpp = xppFactory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(fis, null);
        attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(xpp);
        // Finally you pass the attributes when create the view
        View myView = new View(this, attrs);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```